# How to Align Static-Positioned Nav Bars to the Top-Left Corner?

Tags: html, css

For the past few days, I've been trying to create a nav bar that stays at the top-left corner, and all of the advice that I've found is either someone accidentally adding to the `margin` or needs to use `position:fixed`. How do I align it to the top left corner if I don't want it to be fixed?

```css
li.navi a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:white;
    padding:.3125em;        /* Changes the padding to make the hover effect bigger */
    margin-right:1.2em;
}

ul.navi {
    display:block;
    background-color:black;
    position:static;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}

li.navi {
    display:inline;
    float:right;            /* Prevents the nav bar from glitching out */
    font-size:1.25em;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:Rubik;
}
```

```html
<ul class = "navi">
  <li class = "navi">
    <a href = "https://www.youtube.com/" target = "_blank">
      Item
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class = "navi">
    <a href = "https://www.youtube.com/" target = "_blank">
      Item
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class = "navi">
    <a href = "https://www.youtube.com/" target = "_blank">
      Item
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class = "navi">
    <a href = "https://www.youtube.com/" target = "_blank">
      Item
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class = "titleLi">
    Item
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear the objective of aligning the nav to the top left corner and not  fixing it to the top. If I understand, you just need to keep it on the left side.

Removing the default margin (`margin: 0px;`) of `UL` elements will keep this to the corner of the viewport. If you add 'position:absolute' the element following the NAV element will become overlapped by the nav (in the next example 'test' was overlapped), and you will need more properties to make it work (width, top, left, and box-sizing)

The simplest solution if the `nav` is the first element of the body, is to use:

```
ul.navi {
    background-color:black;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Otherwise, you can get the same effect with more CSS code.

```css
li.navi a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:white;
    padding:.3125em;        /* Changes the padding to make the hover effect bigger */
    margin-right:1.2em;
}

ul.navi {
    background-color:black;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0px;
}

li.navi {
    display:inline;
    float:right;            /* Prevents the nav bar from glitching out */
    font-size:1.25em;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:Rubik;

}
```

```html
<ul class = "navi">
  <li class = "navi">
    <a href = "https://www.youtube.com/" target = "_blank">
      Item
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class = "navi">
    <a href = "https://www.youtube.com/" target = "_blank">
      Item1
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class = "navi">
    <a href = "https://www.youtube.com/" target = "_blank">
      Item2
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class = "navi">
    <a href = "https://www.youtube.com/" target = "_blank">
      Item3
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class = "titleLi">
    Item3
  </li>
</ul>
  <div style='background-color: #ddd; height:3000px; font-size: 24px;'>
  test
 </div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It fixed my problem